# "Missing argument 2 for getParticipantComments(),

Tags: php

im new in PHP and I'im getting and error on "Missing argument 2 for EduSuckr::getParticipantComments(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\elgg\mod\edufeedr\views\default\edufeedr\participant_profile.php on line 55 and defined" in file C:\xampp\htdocs\elgg\mod\edufeedr\edusuckr.php (line 110)

participant_profile.php line 55

```
$comments = $es->getParticipantComments(array($vars['entity']->guid, $vars['participant']->blog_base));
        var_dump($comments);
        if (!($comments && is_array($comments))) {
            $comments = array();
```

and the file edusuckr.php line 110

```
function getParticipantComments($course_guid, $participant_id) {
            return unserialize($this->client->call('getParticipantComments', array($course_guid, $participant_id)));
        }
```

Can someone help please nad explain to me what am I doing wrong.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You're calling the function with a single argument that's an array. You should call it with two separate arguments, not combine them into an array.

```
$comments = $es->getParticipantComments($vars['entity']->guid, $vars['participant']->blog_base);
```